# About dividend percentage

Tags: financial-literacy, dividends

I want to know on what price of a share the percentage is taken.

There are two types of value for a share of stock:

- the market value,
- the face or par value.

What amount I will be paid if I have shares whose market price is $25, and face value/par value is $10, when the company is giving 10% dividend?

Comment: Dividends are a fixed amount per share, not a percentage.

Comment: the dividend yield is calculated as a % of the market price.

Answer (score 6):

Dividend prices are per share, so the amount that you get for a dividend is determined by the number of shares that you own and the amount of the dividend per share. That's all.

People like to look at dividend **yield** because it lets them compare different investments; that's done by dividing the dividend by the value of the stock, however determined. That's the percentage that the question mentions. A dividend of $1 per share when the share price is $10 gives a 10% dividend yield. A dividend of $2 per share when the share price is $40 gives a 5% dividend yield. If you're choosing an investment, the dividend yield gives you more information than the amount of the dividend.